# XBox movie downloads - streaming only?

Tags: xbox-360

I am about to get an XBox 360, and am interested in the HD Movies service that comes with it (Zune Movies, I think).

It wasn't quite clear to me from the XBox website whether movies were downloaded to the Xbox's harddrive, or were streamed. While my ADSL is pretty quick, I'm not convinced that it's up to the job of streaming HD content.

So, can movies be downloaded to the XBox's harddrive before viewing, or is streaming the only option?

I'm in France, by the way - I don't know if that makes any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated with the help of tzenes' comment.

Zune purchases and rentals pop an option to either download or stream. If you rent a movie, you only have access to it for 24 hours after you first begin watching it, and you only have fourteen days from the time of purchase to view it at all.

Comment: Netflix isn't available in France, but downloading Rentals is.  It is, however, worth noting that you can only keep them for 14 days, or 24 hours after starting to watch (which ever is shorter).  Personally, I have no trouble streaming Netflix or Zune over my DSL, but my WiFi is another matter..

Comment: @tzenes: Thanks; completely rewrote answer with your info.